# Phrases with mind

Tags: phrase-meaning

I could find, the phrases

> - wouldn't mind doing something
> - didn't mind doing something
> - don't mind doing something
> - won't mind doing something

can have almost similar meaning. But, as far as I understand the context where `wouldn't mind` is more likely to use as `would like`. For instance:

> I wouldn't mind having some fish.

Could you explain the exact difference between these phrases?

Comment: _Mind_ in the sense of 'would rather not' is a Negative Polarity Item, which means it can only occur in a negative context, which includes all the sentences in your examples. Take off the final _-n't_ suffixes on the auxiliary verbs and see how grammatical they feel. Have you ever heard anyone say "I mind doing the dishes" or "I would mind having more fish"?

Comment: The question is not very clear. The exact difference between *which* phrases — "wouldn't mind" vs. "would like", the four phrases in the bulleted list, or the four phrases plus "would like"?

Answer (score 1):

"wouldn't mind" is a particularly British form of UNDERSTATEMENT for "I would like" or "I would prefer"

Not that you wouldn't find such understatement in American speech, but the Brits are ever so much more adept at such understatement.

Comment: "Wouldn't mind" is perfectly legit and reasonably common in the US.